# How to avoid circular reference while creating interfaces in C# with multiple solutions?

Tags: c#, interface

I am creating an interface that I want to be used in multiple new solutions. Lets call the interface `IBar` and 1 of the new solution `ProjectX`

In `IBar`, I define a method that must return a Model `FooModel` .

The model `Foo` and interface class `IBar` live in the Data Solution. So I add the Data Solution reference to `SolutionX` and I can now easily implement the interface (**DataProject.Interfaces.IBar**) and return the FooModel (**DataProject.Models.FooModel**).

**How do I call the methods in `ProjectX` that implement `IBar` interface from the Data layer??**

If I try to add `ProjectX` reference to Data Layer Solution I get a circular reference error. I am new to interfaces so please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set it up differently, make the `IBar` methods return `IFooModel` things.

And then define `IBar` and `IFooModel` in a separate project.

Interfaces are used to break up circular references, when you find you are creating cycles then something has gone wrong.

Comment: No, not necessarily.  At some point, concrete classes may be useful.

Comment: Yea I had a feeling that I needed to move the Models and classes into its own project. But why return IFooModel if i really jsut need FooModel?

Comment: @Georg - at some point, obviously. But nowadays that link-up is buried deep inside some DI layer.

Comment: I am trying to add interfaces to an existing project, in an attempt to make it work properly, and not a clump of code.

Comment: If i just move these commoon classes into a new project that will essentially solve my problem. You are expercied so please can you explain the benefit of return IFooModel (and how does that worK- SOrry I am trying to learn and understand all this)

Comment: The pivot of whether returning `IFooModel`or `FooModel` is the distinction whether `FooModel` contains any information related to the implementation to the functionality of Bar. For example, a `Rectangle` does not contain any information on how a particular rectangle is computed. Thus, there is no point to hide a rectangle behind an interface.

Comment: Thank you, I hear what you are saying. I just need to think hard about how it actually works. Its a whole new concept, for me and my fellow colleagues, and I need to convince them this is the way forward and not clump codding.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a reference to `SolutionX` in `DataProject`. You can just access the functionality that is hidden by `IBar` via the interface. Thus, in `DataProject`, you might have functionality that takes an `IBar`as a parameter.

```
void Foo(IBar bar) {...}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. But the data layer needs to decide which "module" to call and will get a list of FooModels, apply some filters to it, and then send to our front end just works as normal. So how do I access the results of that particular class if I cannot reference it?

Comment: In that case, you need a dependency injector. So basically, you set up `DataProject` to consume an `IBar` object like above. This method is then called with a dependency injector that injects an implementation of `IBar`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection

Comment: That is really interesting solution using a dependency injector. Unfortunately for this project its too much to handle all at once. But will keep that in mind.I followed Henks recommendation and it already works pretty well. Still open to other answers though.